# CakePHP ServerRequest getQuery() returns blank array in Helper class

Tags: php, class, cakephp, helper

I'm relatively new to Cake, but my project has a fairly large single controller file. As it grew in size, I found myself creating helper functions (at the bottom of the file) to clean up functions and improve readability.

It's reached a point where the controller file got so large it needs a bit further refactoring. I've created the directory **/src/Helpers/** to house my multiple session manipulation functions, called **SessionManipulator.php**.

Since Cake handles session in the request object, SessionManipulator.php looks something like this...

```
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;

class SessionManipulator
{

    function __construct() {
        $this->request = new ServerRequest();
    }
```

You'll note my instantiation of the ServerRequest class: *$this->request = new ServerRequest();*

The majority of my session manipulation functions take into account various GET variables that are set throughout using the program. The issue is, for some reason, when I do something like...

```
if($this->request->getQuery('pid')) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Is behaving strangely. When I troubleshoot and try to take a look at all GET data before the function is called, like...

```
print_r($this->request->getQuery());
```

Returns blank:

```
Array
(
)
```

Meanwhile, a similar **print_r($_GET);** shows the data I'm after:

```
Array
(
    [pid] => 32
)
```

---

So, I think there's something I'm not understanding.

Maybe Cake's ServerRequest class stores GET/POST data into a silo'd off environment I need to make this Helper class accessible to?

---

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that updating:

```
$this->request = new ServerRequest();

to 

$this->request = Router::getRequest();
```

Fixes everything, but I'm not sure I understand why... :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using following line of code, you are creating a New Object of ServerRequest. This is a completely New Object and it does not have any properties of the original HTTP Request.

```
$this->request = new ServerRequest();
```

Cakephp automatically creates a ServerRequest object during an incoming HTTP Request. This Object is available to you inside Controller, View as well as Helper. Only this Object has all the properties of the incoming Request. This Object is available as `$this->request`. You are creating a New Object rather than using the one that is provided by Cakephp. You should be able to access the Cakephp Object using $this->request itself inside Helper. You do not need to create a new instance of it.

You can change your Helper Class like below

```
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;

class SessionManipulator
{

    function __construct() {
        //No need to create a New Instance of ServerRequest.
        //$this->request = new ServerRequest(); 
    }

    function checkPid() {
        //You should still be able to access SereverRequest using $this->request.  
        if($this->request->getQuery('pid')) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it confirms a suspicion I had, that creating a new object in this instance doesn't inherit what I wanted it to. I wish it did, but I'm sure Cake has its reasons, as they do... :)

Comment: This behaviour has nothing to do with Cake. It's very simply how *all* objects work in PHP. Why would you wish that a brand new object is a copy of an existing object, when you already have easy access to the existing object that has everything you need.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks Greg, I understand that. 

I should have instead asked if Cake's ServerRequest class accesses Superglobals directly through getters/setters. I was under that assumption, not necessarily that it's a separate instance. Mostly I was asking because Cake does, at times, act a bit unexpectedly, so I wanted to confirm my suspicions to understand better. Thanks!

Comment: [The manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) covers most of that, I think. Certainly `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_FILES`, `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` are.